# Got timeout reading communication packets

Tags: mysql, errors, timeout

I am trying to create a ssh tunnel to my production database `/usr/sbin/mysqld  Ver 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))`.

When using my ssh-tunnel I get in my mysql error log file this single line:

```
2021-03-02T22:34:33.874444Z 24 [Note] [MY-010914] [Server] Got timeout reading communication packets
```

My query log shows:

```
2021-03-02T22:52:59.338491Z    36 Connect   root@localhost on test_db using TCP/IP
```

On my local machine I get `MySQL server has gone away`.

I have the following configurations for `time` related values:

```
binlog_max_flush_queue_time 0
connect_timeout 90
default_password_lifetime   0
delayed_insert_timeout  300
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp ON
flush_time  0
have_statement_timeout  YES
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
innodb_old_blocks_time  1000
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
interactive_timeout 28800
lc_time_names   en_US
lock_wait_timeout   31536000
log_timestamps  UTC
long_query_time 10.000000
max_execution_time  0
mysqlx_connect_timeout  30
mysqlx_idle_worker_thread_timeout   60
mysqlx_interactive_timeout  28800
mysqlx_port_open_timeout    0
mysqlx_read_timeout 30
mysqlx_wait_timeout 28800
mysqlx_write_timeout    60
net_read_timeout    90
net_write_timeout   90
original_commit_timestamp   36028797018963968
regexp_time_limit   32
rpl_stop_slave_timeout  31536000
slave_net_timeout   60
slow_launch_time    2
system_time_zone    CET
time_zone   SYSTEM
timestamp   1614724734.545546
wait_timeout    28800
```

For `package` related values I got the following:

```
max_allowed_packet  1073741824
mysqlx_max_allowed_packet   67108864
slave_max_allowed_packet    1073741824
```

For `thread` I have:

```
create_admin_listener_thread    OFF
innodb_log_writer_threads   ON
innodb_parallel_read_threads    4
innodb_purge_threads    4
innodb_read_io_threads  4
innodb_thread_concurrency   0
innodb_thread_sleep_delay   10000
innodb_write_io_threads 4
max_delayed_threads 20
max_insert_delayed_threads  20
myisam_repair_threads   1
mysqlx_idle_worker_thread_timeout   60
mysqlx_min_worker_threads   2
performance_schema_max_thread_classes   100
performance_schema_max_thread_instances -1
pseudo_thread_id    32
thread_cache_size   100
thread_handling one-thread-per-connection
thread_stack    286720
```

My verbose log level is:

```
log_error_verbosity 3
show_create_table_verbosity OFF
```

To be honest I tried a lot in changing my values specifically, `max_allowed_packages`, `wait_timeout` and `connect_timeout`.

Any suggestions how to find out which value is the problem?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: There's a number of cases for [gone away](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html). The time from connection to disconnection is missing. Did the server crash (check its error log)? Look though the other possibilities, see if they make sense in your scenario, include how you've eliminated or not those elements in you question.

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;
F) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Take a look at this pastbin. I included all information that you were requesting - https://pastebin.com/LtTQV3DP

Comment: Carol, Let's try again because we need to know if you have Any SSD or NVME devices, The SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; was gathered after 949 seconds rather than 24 hours, SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; posted list stops at innodb_log_compressed_pages with is about 1/2 of the needed data,E) is missing AND we need - Optional very helpful information, if available includes - htop OR top for most active apps, ulimit -a for a Linux/Unix list of limits, iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.